# How do I delete my Facebook friends from the mobile interface?

Tags: facebook, delete

How do I delete my Facebook friends from the mobile interface?. Before the timeline feature there was an "unfriend" button in their profile. However, now I can't find where is it located in timeline version of Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. Just see this screenshot:

[image: Unfriend from Mobile in the new Facebook Timeline]

You have to first click on the "Friends" button, then you see a pop-up drop down list, at the end of which you have the option of "Unfriend".

PS: Kindly note that, based on your mobile model, the mobile browser/facebook app you are using, the kind of script that runs when clicking on "Friends" here may not be supported, in which case you will not be able to "Unfriend" anyone.

Comment: There is no friends button in the profile ,the only two options are message and poke

Comment: @AboobackerMk The Screenshot is taken from mobile, so there has to be.

Comment: The screenshot is smartphone version facebook timeline . I am using a normal phone , verify it from m.facebook.com from your computer browser :-)

Comment: @AboobackerMk It's the same thing I see in my computer browser, you  open it in your computer and cross check it.